# override save method - 'ImageFile' object has no attribute '_committed'

Tags: django, django-models, sorl-thumbnail

I override the save method like below, and get_thumbnails and save with sorl..

But get the error `'ImageFile' object has no attribute '_committed'`

```
class HotelPhotos(models.Model):
    hotel = models.ForeignKey(Hotel, related_name='photos')
    code = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    original = models.ImageField(upload_to="media")
    medium = models.ImageField(upload_to="media", null=True, editable=False)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to="media", null=True, editable=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

        super(HotelPhotos, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        self.medium = get_thumbnail(self.original,
                                    '100x100',
                                    crop='center',
                                    quality=99)

        self.thumbnail = get_thumbnail(self.original,
                                       '50x50',
                                       crop='center',
                                       quality=99)

        super(HotelPhotos, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
self.thumbnail = get_thumbnail(self.original,
                                   '50x50',
                                   crop='center',
                                   quality=99).url
```

solved my problem ..

Comment: saved or solved your problem? ;) P.S don't call `super` save method twice. `super` save will return you an instance use that instance to set additional fields:
`instance = super(HotelPhotos, self).save(*args, **kwargs)`

Comment: It's better to use `.name`, since `.url` will also contain MEDIA_URL, so in the end (if your MEDIA_URL is not empty) you'll get into /media/media/cache/...

Answer (score 0):

I found a similar error recently, which occurred when updating the contents of an ImageField via the django admin.

The error message was: ***'InMemoryUploadedFile' object has no attribute '_committed'***

*models.py:*

```
class MyObject(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80, unique=True, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=80, unique=True, blank=False)
    some_image = ImageField(upload_to='uploads/some/')
    # ... deleted for brevity
```

This wasn't affecting every model, I narrowed it down to this:

*admin.py:*

```
class MyObjectAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # ... 
    def queryset(self, request):
        return super(ShipAdmin, self).queryset(request).only('name', 'slug')
```

The solution was to either alter the admin queryset like so:

*admin.py:*

```
class MyObjectAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # ... 
    def queryset(self, request):
        return super(MyObjectAdmin, self).queryset(request).only('name', 'slug', 'some_image')
```

Or just to get rid of it completely, since it wasn't really needed/relevant any more.